# Las imagenes no se muestran en Azure (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, imagen, azure

Tengo una aplicación web en ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2 que carga perfectamente las imagenes cuando la ejecuto en local:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al subirla a una App Service de Azure, no carga la imagen. Sin embargo, creo que las imagenes se estan subiendo bien a Azure, porque cuando examino el sitio con el Editor de App service, las imagenes aparecen ahi..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo html:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien pudiese ayudarme se lo agradecería muchísimo.
Un saludo!

Comment: ¿Has probado con `<img src="/img/Logo.png"`?

Comment: Usa el gusano `~/`

Comment: Tanto el poner la barra como poner ~/ hacen que no me funcione ni siquiera desde visual studio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola se necesita mas información para entender cual es el problema.

- ¿Cuál es la ruta y nombre del documento que carga la imagen relativa a la raiz de tu aplicación?
- ¿Cuál es la url con la que accedes a ese documento en tu ambiente local? Ejemplo: `https://localhost:1234/Web/Default.aspx`
- ¿Cuál es la url con la que accedes a ese documento en tu sitio de azure? Ejemplo: `https://myazurewebsite/MyAppSlot/Web/Default.aspx`**(no proporciones el dominio real).**

También seria útil que muestres la información de Console y Network de las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador (F12). Procura abrir las herramientas antes de cargar tu página, o en su defecto refresca tu página una vez que hayas abierto las herramientas de desarrollador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la información actual lo que puedo ver es que estás usando una referencia relativa. Tu referencia solo sería válida si lo cargas desde algún documento que se encuentre en la carpeta `Web`.

Efectivamente puedes usar el caracter `~` pero tu referencia debe ser relativa a la raiz del sitio. `~/Web/img/Logo.png`. Además necesitas incluir el atributo `runat="server"`. Esto es porque `~` no es algo que soporte HTML por si solo, mas bien es una syntaxis de ASP y solo funcionará con los elementos que corran del lado del servidor. Por eso es necesario usar runat="server".
Igualmente toma en cuenta que runat="server" solo tiene sentido si lo usas en un archivo aspx, porque es funcionalidad exclusiva de WebForms, es decir no es un atributo valido para html.

Quedaría así:

```
<img src="~/Web/img/Logo.png" runat="server"/>
```

Saludos.